# Real gain of op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

How do I find the real gain of an op amp?

You can find how to calculate the gain of an ideal op amp in many places across the Internet, but I really don't know how to do it for a real op amp with a given open loop gain, Ao= 76 dB, for the given circuit, for example.

[image]

I grounded inputs 2 and 3 to simplify the circuit analysis, so I came up with this equation for the gain:

[image]

But I don't know exactly how to relate this to gain of an ideal op amp so I can find the error in DC gain.

Comment: Hint: start with this equation describing the relationship between op amp inputs and output: \$v_{out} = A_{ol} (v_{+} - v_{-})\$

Comment: This looks like a homework or exam problem, so we will expect you to make a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Do the best you can, show us all of your work, and ask a specific question.

Comment: This is a part of a homework, but i need to actually calculate the error in
DC gain (in relation to the ideal gain), but i got stuck in this part.

Comment: You generally don't do this.  You also need to account for non ideal input impedance as well.  The exercise is worth it, though, because  you learn where the nonidealities kill you.  i.e, the higher the circuit gain, and the bigger the feedback resistor, the less ideal your circuit

Comment: Show us all of your work. Explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: This is somewhat related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/537104/35022

Comment: op amp isn't a proper noun, there's no need to capitalize it.